# How to Integrate Firebase Appcheck in React Native?

Tags: android, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-app-check

Backend we are using Firestore database , I am trying to integrate AppCheck for security that helps to protect the app from unauthorized access .

**Steps I am following**

1. I am following these steps has given by this link (https://rnfirebase.io/app-check/usage)
2. I added SHA 256 in safety Net.

**App.js**

```
import AppCheck from '@react-native-firebase/app-check';

AppCheck().activate('ignore',true).then((res)=>{

  AppCheck().getToken().then((token)=>{

    console.log('token==',token.token);

  })

})
```

**what is the next step ?**

Answer (score 1):

### **It works only in release APK**

Steps I have followed

**Step 1**
Generate Release APK SHA 256 key

**Step 2**

Paste it in field of SHA certificate fingerprints  (Project Setting in firebase) and also in  APP check SafetyNet field.(SHA 256 key should same in project level and App check)

**Step 3**

**APP.js**

import AppCheck from '@react-native-firebase/app-check';

AppCheck().activate('SHA256key',true).then((res)=>{

}).catch((err)=>{
console.log("err");

})

**Step 4**

Now generate release APK and install apk in Device.

**Step 5**

Run app in device and do some activities then you  go to Appcheck and see whether APP is verifying or not (it shows in percentage)

Comment: After adding the 256sha key it says to set up a time limit. Will I have to enter the fingerprints every time manually?

Answer (score 1):

Enabling Appcheck in the app involves few steps

1)Enforcing it in firebase console

2. Adding the SHA256 key in appcheck ( application wise , to match with the one you are using in the app , make sure it is released build sha256 keys )

3)initializing in the application you are implementing (checking the documentation )

4)Activate the appcheck in your application code

you may try to map the issues in one of the steps